# Getting table tr id undefined

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am getting the return value of a table `tr:last id` undefined

```
<table id="tableid">   
  <thead>
   <th>sl.no</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Place</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr id="1"><td>1</td>
  <td>Roy</td>
  <td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr id="2"><td>2</td>
  <td>Doe</td>
  <td>US</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

$("#tableid tbody tr:last").attr('id');
```

Please help.

Comment: show your table to refer

Comment: Your code working fine. See http://jsfiddle.net/Y7ppa/

Comment: Please up vote this question,the question is meaningful i hope.Thanks

Comment: I have updated the question with table for reference , please help

Comment: Please some one up vote this question, i have updated the question clearly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is working fine.check below

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var lastid=$("#tableid tbody tr:last").attr('id');  
alert(lastid); 
});   
   </script> 




 <table id="tableid" >
 <tbody>  

 <tr id="trid1"></tr> 
   <tr id="trid2"> </tr>
    <tr id="trid3"></tr>
 </tbody>
 </table >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var id=$("#table tr:last-child").attr("id");
        alert("id is: "+id);
```

It will display the id of last row of a table. I hope thats what you asked for.
Hope it helps.